# htmlに投稿ごとにsqlのデータをセルのようにして表示

Tags: php, html, sql

htmlに投稿ごとにセルのようにして表示するには$row['xxxx']をなにで表示すればいいですか？ articleだと分配できないようにおもえます

Comment: 短い例はこんな感じに。[PHPで掲示板サイトを作ってみよう【サンプルソース公開】](https://took.jp/bulletin-board/), [PHPで掲示板サイトを作ってみよう【回答編】](https://took.jp/post-1750/) 長い例の始まりはこんな感じで。[ひと言掲示板を作る](https://gray-code.com/php/make-the-board-vol1/)

Comment: ありがとうございます